# ArrayList java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, arraylist, heap-memory

I need to store large number (~4294967294) of objects in list, but I am getting below exception. Please suggest how to store and process large number of objects using java-8.

code:

```
List<String> ipv4FreeAddress = new ArrayList<String>();

for (long i = longValueFrom; i <= longValueTo;  i++) {
                    ipv4FreeAddress.add(DimNumber.getIPFromNumber(String.valueOf(i)));
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:261)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:235)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:227)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:458)
```

Comment: Put them in a `LinkedList` rather then an `ArrayList`, which is backed by an array and is limited by the max size of `int`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm somewhat confused that *you* wrote this. The type of the list is unrelated to the OOME (and in fact, it would probably happen earlier for a `LinkedList` - there's nothing more compact than an array!). But even *if* you put more than 2^31 elements into a list: The `get(int index)` methods and even the internal iterators will be messed up badly even if it *seemed* to work while *filling* the list. The only reasonable approach here could be using some sort of "chunks" or maybe a stream-based method.

Comment: @Marco13 Yes `LinkedList` does not provide good random access performance, but an array is also additional limited requiring continuous memory blocks (as I understand it), meaning that you can run into memory issues if the memory is fragmented - since the OP has not provided their requirements for access, `LinkedList` seems like a more reasonable solution as it's not constrained by the size of `int` or the fragmentation of the memory - of course both have limitations in regards to memory. I also agree, so sort of "cached" list would seem like a better long term solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer Even more confused now. This is *not* about performance. And only secondarily about the memory consumption per se. This is about the fact that in practice, you cannot have a Java Collection with more than 2^31 elements (and still expect it to work properly). For example, `list.size()` returns an `int` value, and if the list contains more than 2^31 elements, then this will return a *negative* value, and mess up all internal structures. You cannot access the last elements *at all*, because you have to call `get(int index)` and cannot pass 3000000000 as the index in there.

Comment: @Marco13 That's a fair point - then make your own linked list which doesn't rely on `int` - got a better solution?

Comment: I reckon a multidimensional array/list could work as long as you index it correctly

Comment: @MadProgrammer It could be an XY-Problem: The question stated *"I need to store... in a list"*, but I **strongly** doubt that there is a profound reason to have >2^32 elements *in memory* at the same time (!). A `LongStream.range(min, max).map(toIpAddress)` would probably do the job. Otherwise, as indicated, chunks (or a "2D list") would probably be the only option...

Comment: @Marco13 I'd probably consider shuffling it off to standalone database (like H2) - let it's query engine take care of it - but as you say - not enough available information

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's the point: It is not clear what the goal is. (and recommending a database here may be like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut). I mean, unless this `DimNumber.getIPFromNumber` call is prohibitively expensive (which I doubt), we're just talking about juggling with some numbers. One can filter, sort and query the numbers *in a mathematical, functional sense*, and likely doesn't need to *store* so much data when it can trivially be *computed* "on the fly".

Comment: @Marco13 Then lets vote to close the questions as to broad or unclear and move on

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, if you need to store 4 billion items in a list, there is a more efficient way to do it. I don't know what you need it for so I can't show you what method to use. Since it looks like you're comparing IPv4 addresses, you could make a function to compare them on-the-fly instead of in a list.

Comment: You could also use a standalone database, probably have better query performance then anything we could write in Java (or would like to re-create)

Answer (score 0):

Have you done some estimations at all?
You could store ipv4 as int (being careful with sign handling) in an int[].

Even then, 4Gi * 4 is 16GiB of memory. You better be having the ram (unless you store to disk) AND have set the -Xmx high enough (ex: java -Xmx20g ...)

Meanwhile, you can save some ips if you skip the multicast ip range, if you don't care about those somehow.

But the big question is what are you trying to do that requires such a live structure?